# Split directories using recursion and string.split

Tags: c#

Here's my problem. I'm using C# and I'm supposed to design a program that runs a directory and list all of the sub-directories and files within. I've got the basic code down, which is shown below:

```
namespace DirectorySearch
{
    class DirectorySearch
    {
        const string PATH = @"C:\Directory Search";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirSearch(PATH);
        }

        static void DirSearch(string dir)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
                    Console.WriteLine(f);
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(d);
                    DirSearch(d);
                }

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is I'm supposed to use stringName.Split('/').Last so the output is all in one straight line, but I have no idea where to place it in the code. The output is supposed to look like:

```
C:\Directory Search
  File1.txt
  File2.txt
    Folder1
    Folder2
      File3.txt
    Folder3
```

and so on... I'm pretty sure I can figure out how to make the tabs work after I figure out how to split them up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you would do it at `Console.WriteLine(f)` but I'd like to point out that using `Split()` is not ideal; `Path.GetFileName()` is much better.

Comment: I am assuming this is a learning exercise since there is a requirement to use string splitting over built in file path functions?

Comment: Ya, it's a class assignment and my professor is one of those "my way or the highway" guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Console.WriteLine(f.Split('\\').Last());
```

Comment: This answer worked perfectly except that it does not display the C:\Directory Search on the first line. Any idea why?

Comment: If that's the only thing missing, you can probably just print that out before calling the recursive function

Comment: That's normally what I would do, but in this case, I think it needs to work within the recursion so my indents stay correct in the output.

Comment: Just a side note: Don't use '\\', instead use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `Path.GetFilename` which  returns directory name (for directories) or file name with extension

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
        Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(f));

foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
{
     Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(d));
     DirSearch(d);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like this is a class assignment and he's required to use Split(), but otherwise yes, GetFileName is much preferred!

Comment: Ya, it's a class assignment that's been driving me crazy for the last few days. This answer worked perfectly except that it does not display the C:\Directory Search on the first line. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I'm Not sure if you'r looking for something like this, but you can try this code

```
namespace DirectorySearch
{
    class DirectorySearch
    {
        const string PATH = @"C:\Directory Search";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(PATH);
            DirSearch(PATH);
        }

        static void DirSearch(string dir, int depth = 1)
        {
            try
            {
                string indent = new string('\t', depth);
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
                    Console.WriteLine(indent + f.Split('\\').Last());//using split
                    //Console.WriteLine(indent + Path.GetFileName(f));//using Get File name

                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(indent + d.Split('\\').Last()); //using split
                    //Console.WriteLine(indent + Path.GetFileName(d)); //using Get File name
                    DirSearch(d, depth++);
                }

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you!